# Slack - Show fullname of user instead of username

Tags: slack-api

Is there a way that in slack, we can show fullname of a user in the channel user list, instead of just the username? Since we have multiple teams and not all the people are familiar with usernames that users pick from different teams, its really difficult to identify who is who unless one goes to their profile or checks their fullname manually.

So, is there a way to display the full usernames for users in the list instead of just the usernames?

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Or [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question in order to move it to superuser

Answer (score 73, accepted):

**For the application side**

Yes there is.  In the window for slack, at the bottom left by your username, there is an up arrow.  Click on that and you will see a preferences option.

[image: Slack Preferences]

Once you are in Preferences, Click on Message Display.  Within this option, you will find "Display real names instead of usernames". Make sure this is checked and click on done.

[image: Message Display]

**For the API Side**

Since this is tagged Slack-api and I'm not sure if this is what you are talking about, within the response of the API from the users.list method, it will return the First/Last name, so you would just have to use it in whatever you are doing.  [Reference the Docs for the Slack API](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list)

```
{
"ok": true,
"members": [
    {
        "id": "U023BECGF",
        "name": "bobby",
        "deleted": false,
        "color": "9f69e7",
        "profile": {
            "first_name": "Bobby",
            "last_name": "Tables",
            "real_name": "Bobby Tables",
            "email": "bobby@slack.com",
            "skype": "my-skype-name",
            "phone": "+1 (123) 456 7890",
            "image_24": "https:\/\/...",
            "image_32": "https:\/\/...",
            "image_48": "https:\/\/...",
            "image_72": "https:\/\/...",
            "image_192": "https:\/\/..."
        },
        "is_admin": true,
        "is_owner": true,
        "has_2fa": false,
        "has_files": true
    },
    ...
]
```

}

Comment: Is there a way to only display first names?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be very useful unless users have actually inputed their first and last name in their preferences, which is NOT required during sign-up.

Comment: And is there a way to change the labels that users pick for themselves?

Comment: In Version 2.5.1 (on Mac), it's moved a little. Your username is in the top left, and this preference is under "Messages & Media" > Display Options

Comment: In newer Windows versions, you can access it by going to File > Preferences > "Messages & Media" > Display Options

Answer (score 1):

If you are channel owner, you can go to: `Team settings -> Name Display -> Expand -> Display first and last names`